# App crashes on production but not in development

Tags: android, proguard

I just launched my brand new app on Google Play but its crashing when i try to open it. The thing is, it used to work just fine in development.

I have ProGuard enabled and i tried disabling it, generating the signed apk and manually installing it on a device.. but my app still won't open.

Since i have Crittercism enabled, after a few tries, i finally got a crash to be reported to the website, and it says:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pizzapp.android/com.pizzapp.android.login.PAWelcomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: a(Activity,int)

PAWelcomeActivity is my main activity!

my proguard-project.txt is like:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable, Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses

-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
```

Does anybody have an idea what this crash is?

Thanks,
Newton

**Update 1:**

Here you can see how my package is organised:

[image: Package]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably obfuscating the Activity lifecycle method names. Make sure not to do that.

Comment: how do i do that? i have updated my answer with my package organisation.. this is my first android app.. so I'm new to proguard and stuff :/

Comment: Don't use proguard then, or copy the contents of your proguard file into a temp folder and then run `android update project -p <path-to-your-project>` and then add your extra stuff into the generated proguard file

Comment: i don't know what that does.. but i just tried adding the code: -keep class com.pizzapp.android.** { *; } to my proguard and it still crashes..

Comment: huh? You don't know what it does so you just didn't do it? Just disable proguard, I suspect you don't need it if you don't know how to use it

Comment: yeahh.. I'm not gonna run a command that i don't know what it does.. and i didn't find anything about it on google.. but i do need to have proguard enabled, i just haven't used it before!

Comment: do you happen to know why -keep class com.pizzapp.android.** { *; } isn't working?

Comment: Glad you figured it out, the command I told you to run is part of the sdk. It bootstraps the project with an ant build file if it doesn't exist and a pro guard configuration if it doesn't exist. It should protect the support lib and the android sdk classes from being obfuscated. With your previous command it looked like you didn't want to obfuscate any of your code

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it… the problem is that i forgot to add the ActionBarSherlock code for the proguard to work with it..

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```